# Create a data frame with predicted values, real values and original features

Tags: python

I have the following dataset:

```
input_data = pd.DataFrame([['This is the news', 0], ['This is the news', 0], ['This is not the news', 1], ['This is not the news', 1], ['This is not the news', 1], ['This is not the news', 1]], columns=('feature1', 'Tag'))
```

That I want to turn into a TF-IDF matrix using the following function

```
def TfifdMatrix(inputSet):
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
    vectorizer.fit_transform(inputSet)
    print("fit transform done")
    smatrix = vectorizer.transform(inputSet)
    print("transform done")
    smatrix = smatrix.todense()
    tfidf = TfidfTransformer(norm="l2")
    tfidf.fit(smatrix)
    tf_idf_matrix = tfidf.transform(smatrix)
    print("transformation done")
    TfidfMatrix = pd.DataFrame(tf_idf_matrix.todense())
    return (TfidfMatrix)
```

Now I transform the data and add the tag

```
input_data2 = TfifdMatrix(input_data['feature1'])
input_data = pd.concat([input_data, input_data2], axis=1)
```

Create a training- and testset

```
train = input_data.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=1)
test = input_data.loc[~input_data.index.isin(train.index)]

train_outcome = train['Tag'].values
train_features = train.drop('Tag', axis=1)
test_outcome = test['Tag'].values
test_features = test.drop('Tag', axis=1)

test_features2 = test['Tag']
```

I not I train a decision tree algorith on it

```
my_tree_one = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
my_tree_one = my_tree_one.fit(train_features.drop('feature1', axis=1), train_outcome)
my_dt_prediction = my_tree_one.predict(test_features.drop('feature1', axis=1))

Now I combine everyhting to get an overview of the original features, the real outcome, the predicted outcome and the TF-IDF matrix

df_final = pd.DataFrame(test_features, test_outcome)
df_final['Prediction'] = my_dt_prediction
```

This however gives me the follwoing data:

```
  feature1   0   1   2   3   4  Prediction
  1      NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN           1
```

Any thoughts on where this goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you are using sklearn already, I would have used [`train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) to do the dataset splitting.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import tree
import pandas as pd

Y = input_data['Tag']
X = input_data.drop('Tag', axis=1)

Xtrain, Xtest, Ytrain, Ytest = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)

# Train and predict
my_tree_one = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
my_tree_one = my_tree_one.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain)
my_dt_prediction = my_tree_one.predict(Xtest)

# Join it all
complete_df = pd.concat([Xtest, Ytest], axis=1)  # features and actual
complete_df['Predicted'] = my_dt_prediction  # creates a predicted column to the complete_df, now you'll have features, actual, and predicted
```

You could eliminate a line and create your predictions column and generate the predictions in one line:

```
complete_df['Predicted'] = my_tree_one.predict(Xtest)
```

--UPDATE--

So in my comment, I was mentioning using a "key" column, but the solution is actually simpler than that.

Assuming your `input_data` contains the original word features and the target variable, then just apply the TDIDF algorithm to your `input_data` and add the TDIDF transformed matrix to the `input_data`.

```
input_data = pd.DataFrame([['This is the news', 0], ['This is the news', 0], ['This is not the news', 1]], columns=('feature1', 'Tag'))

def TfifdMatrix(inputSet):  
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
    vectorizer.fit_transform(inputSet)
    print("fit transform done")

smatrix = vectorizer.transform(inputSet)

print("transform done")
smatrix = smatrix.todense()
tfidf = TfidfTransformer(norm="l2")
tfidf.fit(smatrix)
tf_idf_matrix = tfidf.transform(smatrix)

print("transformation done")

TfidfMatrix = pd.DataFrame(tf_idf_matrix.todense())
return (TfidfMatrix)

input_data2 = TfidfMatrix(input_data['Feature1'])

# Add your TDIDF transformation matrix
input_data = pd.concat([input_data, input_data2], axis=1)

# Now do your usual train/test split
train = input_data.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=1)
test = input_data.loc[~input_data.index.isin(train.index)]
train_outcome = train['Tag'].values
train_features = train.drop('Tag', axis=1)
test_outcome = test['Tag'].values
test_features = test.drop('Tag', axis=1)

# Now train but make sure to drop your original word feature for both fit and predict
my_tree_one = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
my_tree_one = my_tree_one.fit(train_features.drop('Feature1', axis=1), train_outcome)
my_dt_prediction = my_tree_one.predict(test_features.drop('Feature1', axis=1))

# Now combine
df_final = pd.DataFrame(test_features, test_outcomes)
df_final['Prediction'] = my_dt_prediction
```

You should get a dataframe with your original word features, the TDIDF transformed features, your actual values, and your predicted values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Reading your question I realized that my question is a little more specific. I edited my question

Comment: @HenkStraten I added my update. Hopefully that'll answer your question.

Comment: I also added my question, let me know if you have some thoughts

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply... Though, would you have a example of what you mean exactly? Blog post fe?

Comment: I just made an update to my answer. I think its better than using the "key" column method. Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again... but running the script I still face an issue(the end frame only returns NaN). I edited my question

Comment: Seems like your TFIDF matrix might be running into an issue. Based on the sample you put on your question, it doesn't make sense to apply a TDIDF on a numeric value.